# Is there a GUI framework that uses HTML and CSS to build GUIs?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frameworks, native

I mean, other than a browser, of course -- I'm talking about building native applications with HTML and CSS -- not web applications, but *real* native GUIs.

I wonder if such a thing exists?

And what do you think of such a beast? What would the pros/cons of such a system be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [XUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUL).

Comment: Pro's of XUL is rapid application development and no need to learn more stuff about creating user interface, and the con I can think of is that XUL a bit overweighted for creating simple interfaces.

Comment: Thunderbird, for example. And of course Firefox is XUL-based too.